# Theme broken after clearing static content cache - Magento 2

Tags: php, css, magento, magento2

As per title, I flushed the static content cache under the Magento admin panel and it's broken my theme.

I've regenerated the files using `setup:static-content:deploy` on `bin/magento` but that hasn't cured the issue either.

Looking at the front-end of the website, it appears to be a mixture of missing CSS and JS files, some are linking, some are missing.

When I checked `pub/static/frontend/<theme>` there isn't as many files as there should be.

Could anyone shed light on this issue?

Also worth noting that the JS on Magento admin isn't working either so I can't open any menus and images are missing, too.

Comment: You setup multi store and try to open specific store?

Comment: Hi, I can't navigate in magento admin to switch between stores as the js isn't working. One thing I did notice is that there's alot more theme files under 'pub/static/frontend/<theme>/en_US. I believe the store is setup as en_UK but I can't check? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To generate static content for specific store, you can run command like this.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

NOTE: In Magento 2.2, static content is deployed automatically in developer mode but you can force deployment by adding -f at the end i.e.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the database
2. Find the table `core_config_data`
3. Search `dev/static/sign` in path field
4. Changed the value 1 to 0
5. Clear cache

Now check the website in the frontend. It will work fine.